# El objeto de la clase App\Models\Producto no se pudo convertir a int

Tags: laravel

Vale, miren, lo que quiero hacer es que la siguiente consulta:

```
$id_prod_us = Producto::select("id_usuario")->where('id','=',$id);
```

Me devuelva un entero debido a que lo quiero comparar con:

```
$id_usuario = auth()->user()->id;
```

Para que mediante un if() pueda comparar si son iguales o no, el problema es que la consulta en la variable $id_prod_us me sale como:

```
[
 {
  " id_usuario ":  2
 }
]
```

Lo que produce que me salga el error del titulo, la verdad no se como  hacerle, por si las moscas, dejo mis pedazos de código:

ControladorMisProductos

```
 public function edit($id)//FORMULARIO DE EDICIÓN
{
    $id_usuario = auth()->user()->id;
    $id_prod_us = Producto::select("id_usuario")->where('id','=',$id)->get();

    if($id_usuario === $id_prod_us){
        $producto = Producto::findOrFail($id);
        return view('mis_productos.edit', compact('producto'));
    }
   
    $vista = new ControladorMisProductos;
    return $vista->index();
}
```

Como nota, quiero hacer esto, por que no quiero que un usuario pueda modificar los productos de otro usuario cambiando por la URL el id del producto, por ejemplo: http://127.0.0.1:8000/mis_productos/3/edit

Me podrían decir como o que otra solución o recomendación hay.

Comment: Una pregunta: ¿en este caso el `id_usuario` te interesa para hacer otro tipo de operación? Si es sólo para verificar si hay filas con ese valor, es mejor hacer una consulta del tipo `COUNT(*)`  y verificar si trae más de una fila, en cuyo caso, habrá en la tabla datos con ese criterio.

Comment: Quizas deberias probar con `if($id_usuario === $id_prod_us['ìd_usuario']){` para acceder al valor de ese resultado de la consulta (el cual no acabo de ver si realmente es un array u otra cosa como un recurso, en cuyo caso lo deberias recorrer, o bien usar `->first()` en lugar de `->get()` para que te devuelva solo uno)

Comment: Te recomiendo sacar el id de usuarios con `$id_prod_us = (Producto::where('id', $id)->first())->id_usuario;` y en no utilices la comparación triple sino la doble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considera que el uso del método `get` retorna una colección y aunque en este caso solo es un valor el devuelto, va a aparecer como un objeto dentro de un array.

Debido a lo anterior es comprensible que tu condición no se cumpla pues tratas de evaluar la igualdad entre valores de distinto tipo.

Si de ante mano sabes que solo obtendrás una coincidencia de la búsqueda y el único valor relevante de la misma es el `id_usuario`, entonces es tan simple como usar el método [`value()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table):

```
$id_prod_us = Producto::whereId($id)->value('id_usuario');
```

Así ahora en `$id_prod_us` solo se encuentra el valor numérico recuperado

Comment: Si, muchas gracias BetaM, me has dado solución a mi problema, gracias por tu gran aportación :D

Answer (score 0):

el error esta de la siguiente forma
la siguiente consulta me traer una lista de

```
    $data = Producto::select("id_usuario")->where('id','=',$id)->get();
    var_dump($data);
```

el resultado es :

```
[
    {id_usuario:1},

    {id_usuario:2},

    {id_usuario:3},  
    ]
```

si desea traer un solo registro utilice **first()**

si desea traer solo el id_usuario utilice **pluck()**

si dese imprimir todo el array puede usa `**var_dump($data)**`

```
$data = Producto::select("id_usuario")->where('id','=',$id)->first()->pluck('id_usuario');

// $data:  resultado es :4 o null



Ejemplo completo

    <?php  
      public function edit($id){
            $id_usuario = auth()->user()->id;
            $id_prod_us = Producto::select("id_usuario")
->where('id','=',$id)->first()->pluck('id_usuario');
        
            if($id_usuario === $id_prod_us){
                $producto = Producto::findOrFail($id);
                return view('mis_productos.edit', compact('producto'));
            }
           
            $vista = new ControladorMisProductos;
            return $vista->index();
        }
```

otra forma mas fácil de inhabilitar la modificación de los registro por otros usuario seria colocar una condición de los botones

```
@if($id_usuario==auth()->user()->id)
<button >Editar</button>
@endif
```

Comment: La primera no me funciono, pero la segunda, si sería una forma de, gracias :D